# Angular watch on parent directive's controller with require

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a parent and child directive with a controller each, both of which are required in the child directive. I want to watch for changes to a property on the parent directive controller within the link function of the child directive. However, the watch function is fired on initialisation but not subsequently when the property is changed by a button in the parent directive's scope, or by the link function of the parent directive.

Please could somebody explain why this is and how I should resolve it?

**Parent directive**

```
myApp.directive('parentDirective', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        controllerAs: 'parentCtrl',
        controller: function () {
            var vm = this;
            vm.someProperty = true;
            vm.toggle = function () {
                vm.someProperty = !vm.someProperty;
            }
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            $timeout(function () {
                controller.toggle();
            }, 1000);
        }
    } });
```

**Child directive**

```
myApp.directive('childDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        require: ['childDirective', '^parentDirective'],
        controllerAs: 'childCtrl',
        controller: function () {
            var vm = this;
            vm.someProperty = '';
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {

            var controller = controllers[0];
            var parentController = controllers[1];

            scope.$watch('parentController.someProperty', function () {
                controller.someProperty = parentController.someProperty 
                    ? 'Hello world!' : 'Goodbye cruel world';
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**View**

```
<parent-directive>
    <button ng-click="parentCtrl.toggle()">Toggle message</button>
    <child-directive>
        <p>{{childCtrl.someProperty}}</p>
    </child-directive>
</parent-directive>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aanhbvkj/4/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the scope you're watching, the parent controller is 'parentCtrl' instead of 'parentController', so you're not actually watching the property you want to be. The following should work:

```
scope.$watch('parentCtrl.someProperty', function () {
  controller.someProperty = parentController.someProperty 
    ? 'Hello world!' : 'Goodbye cruel world';
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Just couldn't see it!